# Why is the default property giving me an error?

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { User } from 'src/app/model/user/User';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import firebase from 'firebase/app'; // Notice the change here

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  constructor(private auth: AngularFireAuth) { }

  login(email: string, password: string): Observable<User> {
    return new Observable<User>(observer => {
      this.auth.setPersistence(firebase.default.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL).then(() => {
        this.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((firebaseUser:
        firebase.default.auth.UserCredential) => {
          observer.next({ email, id: firebaseUser.user.uid });
          observer.complete();
        }).catch(error => {
          observer.error(error);
          observer.complete();
        });
      });
    });
  }
}
```

On the first default I got this error:

> Property 'default' does not exist on type 'typeof import("(folder directory)/node_modules/firebase/app/dist/app/index")'.ts(2339)

on the second default I got this error:

> Namespace '"(folder directory) /node_modules/firebase/app/dist/app/index"' has no exported member 'default'.ts(2694)

I tried all types of imports and I am still getting this error.

Comment: what version you are using

Answer (score 0):

1st you need to specify what version you are using

meanwhile depend upon the version you have these option

import it like
`import * as firebase from "firebase/app";`

or try

`import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';`

or for new version you can use

`import {initializeApp} from "firebase/app";`

not

`import firebase from 'firebase/app';`